# Insert R DataFrame into SQL Server Table

Tags: r, spotfire

I have been stuck on this for a couple days now...I cant find what the issue could be.  I am using R in Spotfire.  I am trying to insert the results of a dataframe into a sql server 2014 table.  This is an example of what I am using:

```
install.packages("ODBC")
install.packages("DBI")


library(DBI)
library(odbc)

con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
             Driver = "SQL Server",
             Server = "ServerName",
             Database = "DatabaseName",
             UID = "UserName",
             PWD = "Password")
dbWriteTable(conn = con, 
         name = "SQlServerTableDestinationName", 
         value = Datatable)
```

I get this error:

> TIBCO Enterprise Runtime for R returned an error: 'Error in
>   .loadNamespaceImpl(package, path, keep.source, partial) : error
>   executing useDynLib for dynamic library 'rlang' from package 'rlang'
>   loaded from P:/TERR/x86_64-pc-windows-library/4.2 : Error in
>   library.dynam(chname = chname, package = package, lib.loc = ... :
>   Foreign binary rlang could not be loaded'.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the TIBCO community solution suggested here: https://community.tibco.com/wiki/tibcor-enterprise-runtime-r-fast-writeback-sql-server-2016

In your case it would be something like below:

```
dbcon <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect(connection_string )
RODBC::sqlSave(dbcon, dat =  dataf, "SQlServerTableDestinationName")
```

Please let me know if it helps

Comment: I tried that as well and I got: TIBCO Enterprise Runtime for R returned an error: 'Error: cannot convert object to a data frame'.
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.Executors.LocalFunctionClient.OnExecuting()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.Executors.AbstractFunctionClient.<RunFunction>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.Executors.SPlusFunctionExecutor.<ExecuteFunction>d__0.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataFunctions.DataFunctionExecutorService.<ExecuteFunction>d__6.MoveNext()
 The link is for SQL Server 2016, I'm still using 2014

Comment: OK. 2 questions in this case:
1) can you please provide here the `str(df)` of the object you want to upload? I would like to see if anything prevents you from converting your object into data.frame using e.g. `as.data.frame()`
2) is there an option for you to store the file into a .csv format on the drive which will be visible to the SQL server? Not the most elegant way but you will be able to `BULK INSERT` directly into SQL Server from there...

Answer (score 2):

Since insert INTO is limited to 1000 rows, you can dbBulkCopy from rsqlserver package.

dbBulkCopy is a DBI extension that interfaces the Microsoft SQL Server popular command-line utility named bcp to quickly bulk copying large files into table. For example:

```
url = "Server=localhost;Database=TEST_RSQLSERVER;Trusted_Connection=True;"
conn <- dbConnect('SqlServer',url=url)
## I assume the table already exist
dbBulkCopy(conn,name='T_BULKCOPY',value=df,overwrite=TRUE)
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

Comment: Are you sure it is compatible with TIBCO R? According to this doc: (https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/3.1.0/doc/pdf/TIB_terr_R_Compatibility_30.pdf) RSQLServer package has issies under TIBCO.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it finally worked

```
install.packages("RODBC")
library(RODBC)

dbcon <- RODBC::odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL    Server};server=ServerName;database=DatabaseName;uid=UserName;pwd=Password' )
sqlSave(dbcon, DataFrame, "SQLServerName", verbose=TRUE, fast=TRUE, append=TRUE, rownames = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi mate, would mind accepting my suggestion below as correct in this case? It is exactly 1:1 with what you confirm as working :)

Comment: ah sorry about that, I forgot that you mentioned it!  It gave me an error so I had forgot