# Exporting Dataframe into Microsoft Azure SQL Database in R Studio

Tags: sql, r

I have a list of 19 dataframes named `list_dfs`. I recently created a SQL database in Microsoft Azure, and I am trying to create SQL tables from R studio and export these data frames into those tables. An example of one of these dataframes is as follows:

```
                          Item avg_price
1  15 Gal Texas Mountain Laurel       135
2        24" Box Texas Mountain       165
3 24" Box Texas Mountain Laurel       300
4 36" Box Texas Mountain Laurel       550
5     36" Texas Mountain Laurel       300
```

I have established a connection to the SQL database already, and I have this saved to an object named `my_connection`. I have searched through many proposed solutions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51849519/insert-r-dataframe-into-sql-server-table), with no success.

I do not have existing tables in the SQL server, and I am wondering if there is a way to create those tables from R Studio and insert the dataframes into those SQL tables from R Studio as well.

I have tried to do this through a loop, using the `DBI` library like so:

```
for(i in 1:length(list_dfs)){
dbWriteTable(conn = my_connection,
             name = paste(names(list_dfs)[i]),
             value = list_dfs[i],
             row.names = F)
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this error message:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for signature ‘"Microsoft SQL Server", "character", "list"’
```

I have tried searching the error message and got to other posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61620287/why-can-i-not-use-dbwritetable-for-sql-server), and I still cannot find an answer. I am new to how SQL databases work, but I cannot find any solutions to my specific issue.

**More Information**

I connected to my database using this code:

```
my_connection <- dbConnect(drv = odbc::odbc(),                          
Driver = "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server",
server = "servername.database.windows.net",                          database = "database",
uid = "user", 
pwd = "pwd")
```

It shows up on my connections tab. I see my databases, but it still gives me the error above. I still do not know why I am getting this error.

Comment: Try `library(odbc)` and rerun, it seems as if the methods are not registered correctly.

Comment: It still does not work. I cannot seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing a list with a frame, not the frame itself. The clue:

```
... for signature ‘"Microsoft SQL Server", "character", "list"’
```

None of the `db*` functions use a `list` in their signature determination, that should have clued me in right away (but didn't).

To verify this, looking at your code,

```r
for(i in 1:length(list_dfs)){
dbWriteTable(conn = my_connection,
             name = paste(names(list_dfs)[i]),
             value = list_dfs[i],              # <-- single-bracket yields list
             row.names = F)
}
```

Change that to:

```r
for(i in 1:length(list_dfs)){
dbWriteTable(conn = my_connection,
             name = paste(names(list_dfs)[i]),
             value = list_dfs[[i]],            # <-- double-brackets yields a frame
             row.names = F)
}
```

Comment: r2evans, worked like a charm. Classic coding mistake on my part, but we learn everyday. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think we've all been there, it's a common one to make. Some (finger pointing at me) may have made that many many times ...